# Control spacing between boxes using tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I am trying to implement keywords system, by wrapping the keyword with a box using `tikz`. I defined a new command for the box, but I couldn't control the spacing between the boxes, which I would like to be equal between adjacent boxes, regardless of the keyword length inside the box. In the following code I used `\hfill`, but I would like to replace it with a more appropriate and compact spacing, like `0.2cm` for example, instead of spreading them over the whole line.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[top=1cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

 \newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=blue!20,text depth=.5ex,text height=2ex,draw=black,inner sep=3pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {\small #2};\phantom{#2}}
 
\begin{document}
\noindent This is the beginning of the text\\[5pt]
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyw1}\hfill
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{kword2}\hfill
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyword3}\hfill
\end{document}
```

**My questions are**

1. How to control the spacing between the boxes?
2. How can I make the first box start at the same distance from the left as the text above it (the text inside the box starts at the same distance, but the box itself starts a little to the left of the text)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got rid of `[overlay]`, `anchor=text`, and `\phantom{#2}`.  And I added `\hspace{\gapwd}\ignorespaces`.

While I did not use it here, I strongly recommend `\raggedright`, since there are no hyphenation points, and we have not set the gap to be stretchable.

I define `\gapwd` to `.2cm`, which can be changed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[top=1cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand\gapwd{.2cm}
 \newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz\node[fill=blue!20,text depth=.5ex,
  text height=2ex,draw=black,inner sep=3pt, rectangle, 
  rounded corners=1mm,#1] {\small #2};\hspace{\gapwd}\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is the beginning of the text\\[5pt]
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyw1}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{kword2}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyword3}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyword3}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyword4}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{kd5}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{kword6}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyw7}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyw1}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{kword2}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyword3}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyword3}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyword4}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{kd5}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{kword6}
\mybox[fill=gray!50]{keyw7}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a requirement of `\tabwd{2cm}`

Comment: @jsbibra I meant to use it in the macro, instead of hardwiring.

Comment: @jsbibra Actually it was residual from an earlier thought on the solution.  However, I renamed it and use it as the gap setting.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `tcboxes` instead of `TiKZ` nodes. The space between boxes can be fixed with `right skip` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[top=1cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\myk}[1][]{on line, size=small, before upper=\vphantom{ky}, right skip=2mm, #1}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is the beginning of the text\\[5pt]
\begin{raggedright}
\myk{keyw1}
\myk{kword2}
\myk{keyword3}
\myk{keyword3}
\myk{keyword4}
\myk{kd5}
\myk{kword6}
\myk{keyw7}
\myk[colback=red!30]{keyw1}
\myk{kword2}
\myk{keyword3}
\myk{keyword3}
\myk{keyword4}
\myk{kd5}
\myk{kword6}
\myk{keyw7}
\end{raggedright}

\end{document}
```

[image]